# How do I make an Image Slider in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

What is the best way to make an image slider with Xamarin Forms. I've tried using a CarouselPage but it is too slow and uses too much memory.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ImageGallery on Xamarin Forms Labs project](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/blob/master/src/Xamarin.Forms.Labs/Xamarin.Forms.Labs/Controls/ImageGallery.cs)

Like this:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/h51bunhgannsv9v/ImageGallery.mov